# Why radiobutton is not working on this code?

Tags: java, android

When i choose "priority" radiobutton(id=radioButton) for sorting by looking rating,application shut itself down.When i remove RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                rb.findViewById(checkedId);
                if(rb==rb1){
                    Collections.sort(phonelist);
                }
            }
        });
this part it works fine except sorting.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    attachViews();
    this.initializeViews();




    /*RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(this, phonelist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(phoneAdapter);*/

    updateTotal();










}

public void sortData(boolean asc) {
    //SORT ARRAY ASCENDING AND DESCENDING
    if (asc) {
        Collections.sort(phonelist);
    } else {
        Collections.reverse(phonelist);
    }
}


private void initializeViews()
{
    rg=findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1);
    rb1=findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            rb.findViewById(checkedId);
            if(rb==rb1){
                Collections.sort(phonelist);
            }
        }
    });


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(this, phonelist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(phoneAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the listener to this:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton){
        Collections.sort(phonelist);
    }
}
```

I guess `R.id.radioButton` is the id of the RadioButton that was clicked right?

Comment: Yes but when i start the app and click to radioButton app shut itself.I don't know how i applied radiobutton to change view of recyclerview.

Comment: Remove that `rb.findViewById(checkedId);`